# SQL Server Remote Connection from Electron

Tags: node.js, sql-server, electron

I've just developed an desktop app in Electron, and I use a SQL Server for my database operations. I connect to my database with 'tedious' method.

My SQL Server name is `PC` and I cannot change it.

I attempted to share this executable app with another person, but it cannot connect to the SQL Server. Probably it is because my SQL Server is local, I don't know.

I also tried other solutions on here and on the web.

How can I manage it, is there a easy and applicable way?

Comment: Why not run a localdb sql server instance or sqlite database. Of course someone somewhere won't be able to connect to your local computer, since you're probably behind a lot of firewalls etc. Plus sql server isn't good on WAN

Comment: @siggemannen so, how can I do it, what do you prefer?

Comment: google localdb or sqlite and start codin' :) I like sqlite myself

Comment: @siggemannen do you know how to connect nodejs with sqlite? Is there any source that I can look maybe.

Comment: Dude, did you try googling node.js sqlite? This was the first hit https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-nodejs/connect/